# Invisible Attribute Hierarchy under Dimension

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, cube

Below is the snippet of an mdx query used in a report.

with member [Measures].[Leased Coin In]
([Machine Dimension].**[Leased Flag]**.&1 , [Measures].[Coin In])

Now, my question is:
In the cube under **Machine Dimension**, there is no attribute hierarchy name called **Leased Flag.** 
I looked at in the **xmla** script, there is no such name. But, the mdx query pulls result out.

If it is hidden, why does not it appear in the xmla script as hidden/invisible or whatever it is?

If I m missing something, then how do I track it back to find out how it is related with the **machine dimension**.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the query in SSMS? The &1 is not a valid identifier. Identifiers must start with an alpha character or be delimited with square brackets.

It is possible to write a calculated measure that references a non-existant hierarchy or member, but it would just return null. However a reference to &1 should not even get past the parsing stage of the query evaluation without throwing an error.

Comment: Yes, I did run the query in SSMS and Sorry for the typo. The query is run as &[1]. 

But, you are right. It pulled out null. I tired with some arbitrary member and it pulled out null rather than some error. 

Thanx mate.

Answer (score 0):

Old message but for those googling:
When you see something like [Dimension].[Hierarchy].&[1] (I'm assuming the [ ] around the 1 were just left out when entering the message) that is referring to the key of the member in the attribute as opposed to the caption of the member.

The typical place you see this is when using Dimension Security and looking on the Advanced tab or when choosing a Default Member. This lets you rename a member without breaking your cube logic.